# Using a case insensitive Logstash filter

Tags: logstash, logstash-grok, logstash-configuration

How do I change this Logstash filter to be case insensitive?

```
filter {
  if "foo" in [message] {
    mutate { add_field => { "Alert_level" => "5" }}
  }
}
```

I could not get it to work as shown in https://github.com/elastic/logstash/pull/3636

Comment: Isn't this working for you    ` filter {
      if [message] ~ /(?i)foo/ {
        mutate { 
          add_field => { 
           "Alert_level" => "5" 
          }
        }
      }
    }`

Answer (score 12):

The pull request you mention was never merged, so it's not available (and apparently there is no plan to do so).

You can use another syntax (mentioned in one of the comments to your question):

```
filter {
  if "foo" =~ /(?i)message/ {
    ...
  }
}
```

The syntax will match for `message` or `MESSAGE` or even `MeSSaGe`.

Comment: Erm, there are 2 erors in your example. First, you're testing the literal string `foo` against the (constant) regex `message` which never matches, regardless of case sensitivity. And second, you have swapped the places of `"foo"` and `message`. The poster's orignal  expression `"foo" in [message]` basically means "`"foo"` is a substring of `message`" (or `message.contains("foo")` in Java terms). When you do it with a regex, the order is "`variable` matches `regex`", so it should be `[message] =~ /(?i)foo/`.